# RDSDispatchServlet is not available

Tags: apache-flex, blazeds

I have web.xml as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN" "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">
<web-app>

<display-name>HibDemo</display-name>
<description>HibDemo Application</description>

<!-- Http Flex Session attribute and binding listener support -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>flex.messaging.HttpFlexSession</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- MessageBroker Servlet -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>MessageBrokerServlet</servlet-name>
    <display-name>MessageBrokerServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-class>flex.messaging.MessageBrokerServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>services.configuration.file</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/flex/services-config.xml</param-value>
   </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>RDSDispatchServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>flex.rds.server.servlet.FrontEndServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>messageBrokerId</param-name>
        <param-value>_messageBroker</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>useAppserverSecurity</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>10</load-on-startup>
</servlet>


<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MessageBrokerServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/messagebroker/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping id="RDS_DISPATCH_MAPPING">
    <servlet-name>RDSDispatchServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/CFIDE/main/ide.cfm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<!-- for WebSphere deployment, please uncomment -->
<!--
<resource-ref>
    <description>Flex Messaging WorkManager</description>
    <res-ref-name>wm/MessagingWorkManager</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>com.ibm.websphere.asynchbeans.WorkManager</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
</resource-ref>
-->
```

I have downloaded blazeds3.3 and copied all the lib files my lib folder and added the above web.xml file.

Then I have created the Flex 4 project with BlazeDS support. it has been created without any error. Then I have added the datagrid  in the code. While using data-centric driven feature of flex 4 it is asking me username and password. I have checked "No Password Require"
Then it gives me Error Like

```
Error Executing RDS command. Status code 404, Reason: Servlet RDSDispatchServlet is not available
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the RDS stuff isn't in BlazeDS 3.3. As far as I can see, its v4 and above.

So your server is likely not starting the servlet due to the class not being found on the classpath.